# MSSqlServer error:the transaction is completed

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, commit

I get error trying to work with transactions. Without it everything runs fine, but with it I get a strange error: the transaction is completed and cannot be utilized anymore (my translation of the error)

Here is my code till the error:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(gl.constr))
{
    using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlTransaction tr = conn.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                cm.Connection = conn;
                cm.Transaction = tr;
                cm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Bookings (Time, Price, BookingRef, BookingInternalRef)" +
                                  " VALUES(" +
                                  "getdate(), "+ sPrice + ", " + 
                                  db.AddAphens(reference) + ", " +
                                  db.AddAphens(internalBookref) +
                                  ")";
                cm.ExecuteNonQuery();  //this works
                tr.Commit();
```

On the commit the error popups.

Comment: I don't get an error with your code. You mentioned your actual code has multiple SQL statements so maybe the error is related to that. Consider using `TransactionScope` with `ReadCommitted` isolation instead as that will avoid a round-trip and simplify transaction management. Separately, use parameters instead of building the SQL by concatenating strings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the error occurs on the first commit. Anyone has any idea of what the error message signifies? What happens if I do no commit at all, wil the transaction work?

Comment: The error means the transaction started on the client was committed during execution on the server. I don't know why that occurs in your environment since the code you posted doesn't produce the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a explicit transaction declaration `SqlTransaction tr = conn.BeginTransaction()` for a single DML operation since every DML operation will be implicit transaction bound. Thus you can remove your transaction declaration all-together and it should work fine

Comment: This is not the only one operation, after comes other 3 operations to do, and they must be done grouped, that is why I wanted to use a transaction, and by the way that does not explain the error.

Comment: @user1238784 error message says that your transaction has already completed and thus `Commit` call doesn't make sense anymore. Post the actual code if the above posted code is just a mock-up one

Comment: I added first all the other operations and then the commit and it worked.